# Why offset specific in loop mount?

Tags: debian, mount

I am studying the command [here](http://www.biosignalpi.org/index.php/software/development-guide/how-to-install-qt-qwt-and-overclock-rpi) in the post about *How to compile and install Qt, qwt and overclock the RPI*

```
sudo mount -o loop,offset=62914560
<date>-wheezy-raspbian.img /mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs
```

I do `fdisk 2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img` and I get

```
Disk: 2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie.img    geometry: 976/128/63 [7870464 sectors]  
Signature: 0xAA55  
     Starting       Ending  
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]  
------------------------------------------------------------------------  
 1: 0C    0 130   3 -    8  40  32 [      8192 -     122880] Win95 FAT32L  
 2: 83    8  40  33 -  489 232  63 [    131072 -    7739392] Linux files*  
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused        
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

---

Why is offset specific in mount?

Comment: add to the question `fdisk -l date>-wheezy-raspbian.img` please.

Comment: in OSX it is enough to take out the `-l`

Comment: Nothing. Cut out the date. I supposed it was the name of your image. Just fdisk raspbian.img

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Good now? Something wrong?

Comment: Not really, seems you have got an empty file. I downloaded it and it is different.

Comment: I have downloaded the image, will edit your post with a fdisk done in OSX. Your img seems empty...my file has 4029677568 bytes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As 62914560 points exactly 60MiB into the file, I think the best guess would be that the Raspian disk image is actually partitioned.  The offset tells `mount` (or actually `losetup`) the actual offset of the *root* file-system (I suggest this is the second of two partitions, the first most-probably being `/boot` resp. the bootloader/firmware files).

The problem here is that even though the `loop` driver actually supports partitioned images, the number of maximum partitions per `loop` device has to be specified as a module parameter when loading the module (or on the kernel command line).  As there are many distros out there that won't do this by default, `...,offset=XXX` is the most reliable way to cope with partitioned images when `loop` uses the default parameter (which is 0, hence no partition support).

You can test whether your `loop` driver was loaded with partition-support by looking into `/sys/module/loop/parameters/max_part`.  On my current system (ArchLinux), after loading `loop` without parameters this is:

```shellsession
$ cat /sys/module/loop/parameters/max_part
0
```

To enable partitioning-support, you will have to unload `loop` and load it again with the desired value for the `max_part` options, e.g.

```shellsession
# modprobe -r loop
# modprobe loop max_part=8
```

After this, you could try to manually set-up the loop-device for your image by doing

```shellsession
# losetup /dev/loop0 /path/to/<date>-wheezy-raspbian.img
```

Now, you should not only see `/dev/loop0` representing the whole image, but (as long as my theory is correct ;) also have `/dev/loop0p1`, `/dev/loop0p2`, etc., for all partitions in the image (see `losetup` script [example](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/99531/154463)).

**Edit:**

If you want to do this yourself the tedious way (I'd suggest simply reloading `loop` with the correct `max_part` option and simply using the partitions), you could find out which offset is required by using `fdisk` directly on the image-file (shown with an ArchLinux ISO, as I had it on hand, but the idea is the same):

```shellsession
$ fdisk -l archlinux-2016.03.01-dual.iso
Disk archlinux-2016.03.01-dual.iso: 268.3 MiB, 281339392 bytes, 549491 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2237702c

Device                         Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
archlinux-2016.03.01-dual.iso1 *        0 1452031 1452032  709M  0 Empty
archlinux-2016.03.01-dual.iso2        172   63659   63488   31M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

The second partition starts at sector 172 with a sector size of 512 bytes.  Multiplying both values gives you the offset in bytes, thus to mount the partition, you'll use:

```shellsession
# mount -o loop,offset=$((172*512)) archlinux-2016.03.01-dual.iso /mnt
# ls -l /mnt
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 2048 Mar  1 15:49 EFI
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 2048 Mar  1 15:49 loader
```

Voila.

Comment: I want to use Raspian Jessie so it means that I have to find the corresponding number for it. How can you get it? What is this XXX? Can you have some general thing there?

Answer (score 2):

As per the "losetup" man page.

> -o, --offset offset
>       the data start is moved offset bytes into the specified file or device

e.g. If you have "dd" of a device then you can mount any of it's partition by using *offset* option.

This offset value is calculated by multiplying the start value of partition by sector size

e.g.

```
SHW@SHW:/tmp # fdisk -lu 040614.dd
Disk 040614.dd: 1.9 GiB, 2048385024 bytes, 4000752 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5324798e

Device                          Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
040614.dd1 *       2048   30719   28672   14M 83 Linux
040614.dd2        30720 1054719 1024000  500M 83 Linux
040614.dd3      1054720 1095679   40960   20M 83 Linux

SHW@SHW:/tmp # mount -o loop,offset=`echo 1054720 \* 512|bc` 040614.dd1 /mnt/loop
```

**UPDATE:**

*040614.dd* is created by following command:

```
SHW@SHW:/tmp # fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.9 GiB, 2048385024 bytes, 4000752 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5324798e

Device                          Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1 *       2048   30719   28672   14M 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2        30720 1054719 1024000  500M 83 Linux
/dev/sdb3      1054720 1095679   40960   20M 83 Linux

SHW@SHW:/tmp # dd if=/dev/sdb of=040614.dd
```

Comment: How did you find first `040614.dd`? I really like your second command because it is general i.e. exactly what I need because I have so many images that I want to test. Anything about that thing would be greatly appreciated.